# IOS drawing lines on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm thinking of a way to create a line drawing functionality when a user might tap the screen and move his finger on it and see the line or an arrow moving with his finger. I know how to draw a line between the starting and the end points using the bezier paths but I'm now thinking of a way to somehow let the user observe the line changing with the touchesMoved method. I was thinking about saving the temporary path and removing it and substituting it with the new one in the touchesMoved method but I'm not sure whether this approach will work good. So I would be grateful to hear any suggestions how to enable that visual tracking of user actions with the line.

Answer (score 1):

For free hand drawing you should try the touch method:
touchesBegan:WithEvent:, which are declared in the UIResponder class from which UIView inherits. We can write code to handle the touch events whatever way we like. For more information please read the tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-freehand-drawing-on-ios--mobile-13164

I hope this help for you.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do free hand drawing (this is the source I've used to learn how to draw) but I need to draw arrows and lines using touch methods too.